# Difference between apoc.cypher.mapParallel and apoc.cypher.mapParallel2 in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

What is the difference between procedure `apoc.cypher.mapParallel` and `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2`? The [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.4/cypher-execution/running-cypher/) for both has an identical help text, `Call apoc.help("mapParallel")` reveals an identical signature. In which parallelisation scenario do I use which procedure?

Comment: `apoc.help` actually returns different signatures for them (tested in neo4j 4.0.0, with APOC 4.0.0.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/4.0/src/main/java/apoc/cypher/Cypher.java, `mapParallel2` has two more input parameters: `partitions` and `timeout`. It's clear what `timeout` does. `partitions` is `100*number of cores` by default. That's what used in `mapParallel` and `mapParallel2`. The only difference is that you can change it if you want when you call `mapParallel2`.